# Python Celery start same worker in different time issue

Tags: kubernetes, celery

I have a celery task to process database data.
Then a celery worker is started and process related tasks. When I start another worker in a different server via k8s or by myself, this new worker will steal the existing worker task (same task id). And the existing worker will get another task from RabbitMQ.
The existing worker's task be terminated.

PS: If I started 2 workers at the same time, no such issue.

I tried different configurations, like `CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1`, `-O fair`, `ELERY_ACKS_LATE = True`, and also tried to use Redis to mark the task id but it still fails.